keycloak mapping from azure AD IdP
I am using keycloak as IdP and proxy to authenticate against other Idp. So far I have configured an azureAD provider.
I am using at Identity providers section the option to map a role from azureAD to a new role only at my keycloak client but seems i cant make it work even when i am following the same steps from many examples.
This is the token i am receiving from azureAD with the desired attribute:
{
  ...
  "roles": [
    "Admin"
  ],
  ...
  "ver": "2.0"
}

And this is the configuration I have at keycloak.
Sync mode: Force
Mapper Type: Claim to Role
claim: roles
Claim Value: Admin
Role: KeycloakClientAdminRole
What am I missing? I need to configure some other option at keycloak?
When i set to true this option

The login process start failing

Check whether the Keycloak client that you are using has the KeycloakClientAdminRole role defined. If the role is not defined for the client, then the mapping will not work.
